# Using C# to retrieve data from a Google search

Tags: c#, google-api

Here's what I want the program to do:

1. Read a text file (the text file contains random search criteria like "sunflower seeds", "chrome water faucets", etc) to retrieve a search phrase.
2. Submit the search phrase to Google and retrieve the first four URLs.
3. Retrieve the Google Page Rank of each of the returned URLs.

Being a neophyte C# programmer, I can handle #1 easily.  Unfortunately, I've never dealt with using the Google APIs before.  I do have a Google API key and I'm aware that there is a search limit using the API.  At most, I'll probably use this on a dozen search phrases (or "keywords") per day.  I can do this manually, but I know there has to be a way to do this with a C# program. I've read that this can be done using AJAX, but I don't know AJAX and I'd rather this just be an executable program on my PC rather than a web-based app.  A push in the right direction from someone would be a big help.  Also, I really don't want this to be a "screen-scraper", either.  Isn't there a way that I can get the info (URLs and Page Rank) from Google without having to scrape a returned HTML search page?

I don't want anyone to write the code for me, just need to know if it's possible and a push towards finding the information on how to accomplish it.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't want anyone to write the code
>   for me, just need to know if it's
>   possible and a push towards finding
>   the information on how to accomplish
>   it.

Look into the WebClient class

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check it out right now.  I appreciate the link!

Comment: Yep, this helps me out a lot.  Again, I greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
googleSearch = @"http://" + @"www.google.com/#hl=en&q="+@query;
```

where query is the string of your search.